# ImportError on different server

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, pytz

I have a python script that uses the pytz module and it runs successfully on one server. But I have moved the script to a different server (over SSH), and now when I try to run the code there I get:

```
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

Is there an easy way I can get it to run? I believe I don't have the permissions to download new modules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to install this module on your new ssh server, by using:

`python -m pip install pytz`

if you haven't permissions to download any module, try to use a common similar, or compile this script to a `.sh` or `.exe` runnable file, on your developer machine.

Comment: When running that command I get the error `/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip`

Comment: well, in this case, follow [this tutorial](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to install pip on your server.